# Inserting into a database using PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php
// Create connection
$DB=mysqli_connect("88.80.185.241","Test","","Test");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} else{
  echo "Connected";
  echo "<br>";
}
// 

$Table = mysqli_query($DB, "SELECT * FROM TBL_Time");

while($Row = mysqli_fetch_array($Table)){
    echo "Date: " . $Row['Date'] . " | Time: " . $Row['Time'];
    echo "<BR>";
}


$Row = mysqli_fetch_array($Table);

$Date = date("d-m-Y"); 
$Time = time();

echo "Date: " . $Date . " | Time: " . $Time;

$Insert = "INSERT INTO TBL_Time (Date, Time) VALUES (:D, :T)";
$PreQuery = $DB->prepare($Insert);

$PreQuery->bind_param(':D', $Date);
$PreQuery->bind_param(':T', $Time);


$PreQuery->execute();

?>
```

Why isn't the insert working? I can read the Database but can't insert. I've checked the privileges and they seem fine.

I've tried moving things around but haven't got anywhere

Comment: Add some error checking and you'll find out rather quickly.

Comment: not sure but i think Date is a reserved word, if you named your columns so you have to escape it.. like (\`Date\`, \`Time\`) (backticks)

Comment: You're using PDO placeholders syntax, use `$var` and `?` not `:var`

Comment: $DB is not an Object but your using PDO functions which needs an Object!

Comment: @Rufinus `date` nor `time` are reserved words, see the last part of http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using PDO-style placeholders syntax with `:` instead of `?` as well as the `s` parameter to tell it it's a string in the binds.

Those two types of placeholders do not intermix/interchange with each other.

```
$Insert = "INSERT INTO TBL_Time (Date, Time) VALUES (?, ?)";
$PreQuery = $DB->prepare($Insert);

$PreQuery->bind_param('s', $Date);
$PreQuery->bind_param('s', $Time);
```

---

Read up on both and their differences:

- [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
- [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)

---

***Footnotes:***

Quoting Fahim:

> *Use one variable of type `DATETIME` instead of two variable of type `varchar`*

Comment: I know this is right answer, but if possible edit answer asking OP to use one variable of type `DATETIME` instead of two variable of type `varchar`

Comment: ah thanks I didn't realise the difference between PDO and mysqli

Comment: @FahimParkar Good point. I will +1 your comment if you want to leave it in there. I will make a note of it with credit to you.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect, because $DB is not an Object but your using it as an Object! (Objects are only created if the keyword new is used)

```
$Insert = "INSERT INTO TBL_Time (Date, Time) VALUES (:D, :T)";
$PreQuery = $DB->prepare($Insert);

$PreQuery->bind_param(':D', $Date);
$PreQuery->bind_param(':T', $Time);


$PreQuery->execute();
```

So write this instead the code above:

```
$Date = mysql_escape_string($Date);
$Time = mysql_escape_string($Time);
mysqli_query($DB,"INSERT INTO TBL_Time (Date, Time) VALUES ($Date, $Time)");
```

Comment: Although in this case the variables are generated by the script and are safe to use, I would never recommend replacing a prepared statement with a query where the variables are injected directly. And unquoted.